# Closure of globe

Tags: general-topology

Is it true that $\overline{K}(x,r) = \mbox{cl}K(x,r)$ ?

I suppose that it is true. In euclidean space I can see that it is true. But maybe in other metric spacies we can find counterexample? If not, how can I prove that fact?

Comment: In a discrete metric space $X$ with at least two elements we have $\overline{B}(a,1) = X \ne \{a\} = \overline{B(a,1)}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are numerous counterexamples. Take the metric $d$ on $\Bbb R$ defined by $$d(x,y)=\min\{|x-y|,1\}\;;$$ this is a metric, and it even generates the usual Euclidean topology. However, $\overline{B}(0,1)=\Bbb R$, while $\operatorname{cl}B(0,1)=[-1,1]$.